# Eliminating Vine Weevils without neonicotinoids

Tags: pest-control, pesticide

I recently acquired a number of plants for ground cover.  After planting, I noticed that I had an infestation of Vine Weevils, almost certainly from the new plants.  I have pulled out the new plants and burnt them.

However, I would like to try to ensure the weevils are all gone.  As far as I can see, the recommended treatment is acetamiprid, which is a neonicotinoid.  This is, of course, very damaging to bees.  I know of half a dozen beehives within half a mile of my garden and have several bumblebee nests in my garden.  I would prefer something more friendly.

Are there any such pesticides that can be put on the affected soil for a quick purge of any remaining larvae?

Comment: Bravo for thinking of other animals in your area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acetamiprid is, as you say, not desirable to use in a garden; however, for vine weevil, the treatment is not sprayed, it is applied as a soil drench to kill the larvae, meaning it is less likely to affect pollinating insects. Regardless, it doesn't  work very well in open ground and is not recommended for this purpose from an environmental point of view - it is more effective for potted plants. There are nematode treatments available (Nemesys vine weevil treatment) which are watered onto the soil when conditions are appropriate; products may vary in recommendations for use, with August/September being the prime time, but they can be used from end of March onwards if the weather is warm enough.

Damage from vine weevil adults  may be obvious on foliage, but does not usually kill the plant, it is the larvae which feed on roots before they emerge as adults that are more of a threat. Further information and guidelines as to how to manage vine weevil here https://www.rhs.org.uk/biodiversity/vine-weevil

Comment: I used Nemassist twice with good results, though that was for curl grubs